# Creating lists of lists in a pythonic way

Tags: list, matrix, python

I'm using a list of lists to store a matrix in python. I tried to initialise a 2x3 Zero matrix as follows.

```
mat=[[0]*2]*3
```

However, when I change the value of one of the items in the matrix, it changes the value of that entry in *every* row, since the id of each row in `mat` is the same. For example, after assigning

```
mat[0][0]=1
```

`mat` is `[[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]`.

I know I can create the Zero matrix using a loop as follows,

```
mat=[[0]*2]
for i in range(1,3):
    mat.append([0]*2)
```

but can anyone show me a more pythonic way?

Comment: There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> mat = [[0]*2 for x in xrange(3)]
>>> mat[0][0] = 1
>>> mat
[[1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Or, as a function:

```
def matrix(rows, cols):
    return [[0]*cols for x in xrange(rows)]
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
>>> cols = 6
>>> rows = 3
>>> a = [[0]*cols for _ in [0]*rows]
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> a[0][3] = 2
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

This is also discussed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691946/short-and-useful-python-snippets/692458#692458):

```
>>> lst_2d = [[0] * 3 for i in xrange(3)]
>>> lst_2d
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> lst_2d[0][0] = 5
>>> lst_2d
[[5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: +1 - nice stuff.  I'm just learning Python, so I greatly appreciate seeing snippets of "pythonic" code.

Comment: "`[0]*rows`" part is misleading; you're creating a list that is not used in any way except its length. Use either `xrange(n)` or (less likely) `itertools.repeat(None, n)` to do something `n` times in Python.

Answer (score 7):

This one is faster than the accepted answer!
Using xrange(rows) instead of [0]*rows makes no difference.

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> rows,cols = 3,6
>>> a=[x[:] for x in repeat([0]*cols,rows)]
```

A variation that doesn't use itertools and runs around the same speed

```
>>> a=[x[:] for x in [[0]*cols]*rows]
```

From ipython:

```
In [1]: from itertools import repeat

In [2]: rows=cols=10

In [3]: timeit a = [[0]*cols for _ in [0]*rows]
10000 loops, best of 3: 17.8 us per loop

In [4]: timeit a=[x[:] for x in repeat([0]*cols,rows)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.7 us per loop

In [5]: rows=cols=100

In [6]: timeit a = [[0]*cols for _ in [0]*rows]
1000 loops, best of 3: 368 us per loop

In [7]: timeit a=[x[:] for x in repeat([0]*cols,rows)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 311 us per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

I use

```
mat = [[0 for col in range(3)] for row in range(2)]
```

although depending on what you do with the matrix after you create it, you might take a look at using a NumPy array.

Comment: I'm going to explore NumPy at some point, but for my current problem, a list of list is enough.

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
col = 2
row = 3
[[0] * col for row in xrange(row)]
```

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
m, n = 2, 3
>>> A = [[0]*m for _ in range(n)]
>>> A
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> A[0][0] = 1
[[1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Aka List comprehension; from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists 
without resorting to use of     
map(), filter() and/or lambda. 
The resulting list definition tends often to be clearer    
than lists built using those constructs.
```

Answer (score 2):

If the sizes involved are really only 2 and 3,

```
mat = [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

is easily best and hasn't been mentioned yet.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything itertools can't do? :)

```
>>> from itertools import repeat,izip
>>> rows=3
>>> cols=6
>>> A=map(list,izip(*[repeat(0,rows*cols)]*cols))
>>> A
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> A[0][3] = 2
>>> A
[[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```