# Debugging trick when working with lists

Tags: python, debugging, list

I came accross this snippet:

```
li = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print "\n".join(li)
```

The author says:

> This is also a useful debugging trick when you're working with lists.

What is the trick here?

[source](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/all_together.html)

Comment: Why isn't he just using the pprint library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing a list like that is **useless** for debugging:

(1) If any of the list items are not strings, you will get an exception.

(2) Your stdout may not be able to display the strings, resulting in an exception or just gibberish.

(3) You won't see the difference between (for example) tabs (`\t`) and multiple spaces.

Much better:

Python 2.x : `print repr(li)`

Python 3.x : `print(ascii(li))`

**Update** Here's what can happen with `print(li')` on Python 3.x (it's problem 2 above):

```
>>> li = ['\u0404']
>>> print(li)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python32\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0404' in position
2: character maps to <undefined>
```

Note that `print li` "works" on Python 2.x only because `repr()` is called implicitly. In general one should just do `print repr(thing)`. Note also that `print(li)` can fail on Python 3.x because it implicitly calls `repr()`, not `ascii()`

**Update 2** If you want to find all non-strings in a list, do it explicitly, don't rely on "tricks":

```
>>> def check_list(li):
...     for x, v in enumerate(li):
...         if not isinstance(v, (str, unicode)):
...             print "Type %s (%r) at offset %d" % (type(v), v, x)
...
>>> check_list(['\xff', 2, u'\u0303', 4.0])
Type <type 'int'> (2) at offset 1
Type <type 'float'> (4.0) at offset 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The "trick" is printing each of the elements of a list in separate lines, that's all.

Comment: That can be done with `for item in li: print item` This is the same trick?

Comment: It's a matter of style, both snippets of code do the same, essentially. It might be argued that using `join` is more efficient than using an explicit loop

Answer (score 1):

The "trick" is that `"\n".join(li)` takes less time to write all the elements of **li** on the display than the following code:

```
for x in li:
    print li
```

If **li** has few elements, the difference isn't really perceived.
But test the difference with a long list, and it will be evident

The word "trick" is a little excessive, though.

Comment: So, it has nothing to do with debugging the code and searching bugs?

Comment: I agree with you, I don't see what that has specifically to do with debugging. _ By the way, isn't me that would have written this "trick" info ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're telling that you're the author? Your answer is useful. I'm only curious if there is some debugging trick.

Comment: Your question reminded me that I once wrote a post saying that ``"\n".join(...)`` is very useful and I wondered if I wasn't the author of the citation , though this latter refers to debugging ( but ideas may vary with time). I have searched for this post: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5694834/551449) and now I can see that I am not the author of the citation implying debugging.