# python cookbook for beginners?

Tags: python-2.7, cookbook

I know there's a python cookbook, and it seems to be a good one. But it also seems to be aimed more towards intermediate and advanced users.

Does anyone know of something along the lines of a python cookbook for beginners?

I'd really like some useful examples of code that I could use right away for fun things to learn about python programming, that ISN'T the absolute basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small set of resources you may want to study:

- [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python)
- [What are some cool Python tricks?](http://www.quora.com/Python-programming-language-1/What-are-some-cool-Python-tricks)
- [Short (and useful) python snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691946/short-and-useful-python-snippets)
- [30 Python Language Features and Tricks You May Not Know About](http://sahandsaba.com/thirty-python-language-features-and-tricks-you-may-not-know.html)
- [Python snippets](http://sebsauvage.net/python/snyppets/)

There are a lot of interesting examples that could help you understand the language better.

Answer (score 1):

My professor recommended for me a book called "think python like computer scientist".
I'm reading it for now , it's very good at python and methods of thinking .
You can download it from :
https://greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkpython.pdf